# Chrome extension has FireBreath plugin... Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject

Tags: c++, windows, dll, google-chrome-extension, firebreath

***My deepest apologies. The file wasn't copied into the correct directory and thus could not be read. The extension works across all Windows platforms after all. This is a reminder to perform proper error handling at all times.***

**Straight question:** Do I need to upload more than the FireBreath generated .dll file (needing proper .js, .html, and .json are obvious) for a FireBreath plugin within a Chrome extension?

**Big picture:**
FireBreath generates a .dll and I believe putting loading this .dll file into the Chrome extension folder I upload using chrome://extensions/ unpacked is sufficient. In other words, I think I do not need to upload additional C++ code. Calling *plugin.openUserIdFromFile()* generates my error.

**Success:** I loaded the desktop username from a file to a Chrome extension using a NPAPI FireBreath plugin. It works on the Windows desktop on which the plugin was developed.

**Failure:** *Error calling method on NPObject.* Error is received on all Windows environments: XP, 7, or 8 outside the development environment.

**Known:** A buddy ran http://www.dependencywalker.com/ software on it and found that IEShims.dll was a missing dependency in his environment, but I included it in the uploaded folder to no avail.

**JavaScript Chrome extension makes call to FireBreath plugin dll:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(getAllChromeTabs, 10000);

    var plugin = document.getElementById("pluginId");

    while (user.length < 1) {
        user = plugin.openUserIdFromFile();
    }
    console.log(user);
});
```

**C++ FireBreath plugin function called from Chrome Extension:**

```
std::string LabStatsPluginAPI::openUserIdFromFile()
{
    std::string aTempFileName = "aTempFileName";

    DWORD nBufferLength = MAX_PATH;
    LPTSTR lpBuffer = (new TCHAR[nBufferLength]);
    DWORD tempPath = GetTempPath(nBufferLength, lpBuffer);

    char* localTempPathArray = new char[nBufferLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < nBufferLength; i++) {
        localTempPathArray[i] = (char)lpBuffer[i];
    }
    std::string localTempPath(localTempPathArray);
    localTempPath = localTempPath + aTempFileName;

    std::ifstream streamFromFile;
    std::ifstream::pos_type fileSize;
    streamFromFile.open( localTempPath, std::ios::in|std::ios::binary|std::ios::ate );

    char* userNameString;
    int userNamesize = streamFromFile.tellg();
    streamFromFile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    userNameString = new char[userNamesize];
    streamFromFile.read(userNameString, userNamesize);

    delete[] lpBuffer;
    delete[] localTempPathArray;

    std::string userNameSafeString(userNameString);
    delete[] userNameString;

    return userNameSafeString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following modification to the C++ (the if statement inserted) fixes the function.

```
char* userNameString;
int userNamesize = streamFromFile.tellg();
if (userNamesize < 1) {
    return ""; // no file found
}

streamFromFile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
userNameString = new char[userNamesize];
streamFromFile.read(userNameString, userNamesize);
```